# Python f-string with variable width alignment

Tags: python, while-loop, alignment, width, f-string

I want to print below code.

!!!!**
!!!****
!!******
!********

So I use while loop with i, j. But, in some parts, the output of ! becomes weird.
I tried some case, there is no problem if the i and j are in ascending order, but there is a problem if they are in descending order. Below my code, print(i, j) means there was no problem with the value of i and j.

```
i = 0
j = 6
s1 = ""
s2 = ""
while True:
    i += 1
    j -= 1
    if i > 5: break
    s1 = f"{s1:!<{j}}"
    s2 = f"{s2:*^{i*2}}"
    print(i, j)
    print(s1+s2)
```

```
1 5
!!!!!**
2 4
!!!!!****
3 3
!!!!!******
4 2
!!!!!********
5 1
!!!!!**********
```

Comment: When I use 5-i instead of j, result were same.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you over-complicating  things a bit here?
If it's the pattern you are looking for here:

```
def print_pattern(bangs: int, stars: int)->None:
    output = f"{'!'*bangs}{'*'*stars}"
    print(output)
```

Care to provide some more explanations about what do you expect actually?
Is the total number of chars fixed?
Is it the sum of i and j, something else?

```
i, j = 0, 6
total = i+1
while i+j == total:
    if i>5:
        break
    print_pattern(bangs=i, stars=j)
    i+=1
    j-=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use only 1 print, and include 'end' with a space:

***print( ...., end = " ")***

```
i = 0
j = 6
s1 = ""
s2 = ""
while True:
    i += 1
    j -= 1
    if i >= 5:
        break
    s1 = f"{'!'*(j-1)}"
    s2 = f"{s2:*^{i*2}}"
    print(s1 + s2, end=" ")
```

Output:

```
!!!!** !!!**** !!****** !********
```

I also modified your break clause.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want a space after each sequence of asterisks but probably not at the end of the output. Therefore:

```
M = 4
N = 2

for m in range(M, 0, -1):
    print(f"{'!' * m}{'*' * N} ", end='')
    N += 2

print('\b')
```

**Output:**

```
!!!!** !!!**** !!****** !********
```

Answer (score -1):

I found wrong thing.

`s1 = f"{s1:!<{j}}"` in this part, value(j) is max value.

So, s1 already full.
At the end of the loop, s1 must be initialized.

I should add `s1 = ""`

Comment: I don't know...Basically what you should is:

- describe the task clearly and not by ambiguous, out of context pieces  

- not declare s1, s2 outside the loop as they do nothing

- change names to something meaningful

- use f-string consistently and do not use "+" for strings if it's not needed

Please don't take it as an offense, but the communication is really poor here, although I did my best to understand.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).